# Populate Active Directory data into a SharePoint list form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, custom-list, user, active-directory-import

I have one custom list with fields like

- ID,
- Name,
- Phone no

When Ii add a new item to the list a new item form will be opened. While filling the form by entering the first field (ID), I want other fields to be auto-populated from Active Directory.

Is it possible through Browser (UI) or from SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your SharePoint version is 2013 and User Profile service is working fine on your environment. You can use **REST API** to get user information from ***User Profile Service***.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://<site url>/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager
    /getuserprofilepropertyfor(accountame=@v, propertyname='PictureURL')
        ?@v='i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7Cuser%domain.onmicrosoft.com'",
  type: "GET",
  headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```

[msdn reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn790354.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this piece of code to fetch data from Active Directory using JavaScript and then with the help of SPUtility or JavaScript set the value of fields.

```
function getUserName() { 
var wshNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network"); 
var userName = wshNetwork.UserName; 
return userName;
} 
function getAD(userName) {  //var name = userName.split(".");
objConnection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection"); 
objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"; 
objConnection.Open("ADs Provider"); 
objCommand = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Command"); 
objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection;  
objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT sAMAccountName, ID, Phone FROM 'LDAP://ad.mycompany.com/OU=User Accounts,OU=User Directory,DC=ad,DC=mycompany,DC=com' WHERE objectCategory='user' and sAMAccountName = '" + userName + "'";   /* Next up is the command itself.*/  
objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute();   /* Then we execute the command */   /* Once executed, the command will return an enumeration of the results.*/   
var Id, Phone, Name; 
if (objRecordSet.RecordCount == 1) {  
    objRecordSet.Movefirst;   
    Id= objRecordSet.Fields("Id").value;  
    Name= objRecordSet.Fields("givenName").value;  
    Phone= objRecordSet.Fields("Phone").value; 
} 
else  {   
    Id= "";  
    Name= "";  
    Phone= ""; 
} 
objConnection.Close;  
return userMail + ";" + firstName + ";" + lastName;
} 
var AD = getAD(getUserName()).split(";"); 
var Id= AD[0];
var Name= AD[1];
var Phone= AD[2];
```

You can use above variables to set Fields in edit or new form using SPUtility.
For Eg.

```
SPUtility.GetSPField('Name').SetValue('Hello world!');
```

For more reference on `SPUtility` refer this [link](https://sputility.codeplex.com/).